# Object or column name is missing or empty

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this problem in C#, I have already run this query in SQL Server and works

SQL query

```
SELECT Mineria.dbo.Usuario.ID_Usuario, Mineria.dbo.Usuario.Sexo, Mineria.dbo.Usuario.Idioma, Mineria.dbo.Usuario.Edad, Mineria2.dbo.ARTISTA.Nombre_artistic
INTO Mineria.dbo.Objeto
FROM Mineria.dbo.Usuario
INNER JOIN Mineria2.dbo.ARTISTA ON Mineria2.dbo.ARTISTA.Id_Artista=Mineria.dbo.Usuario.ID_Usuario
AND Mineria.dbo.Usuario.ID_Usuario BETWEEN 35 AND 70
ORDER BY ID_Usuario ASC
```

I can't find the problem on the c# code

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(string.Format("
Select '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "' , '" + maskedTextBox2.Text + "' 
INTO Mineria.dbo.Objeto FROM Mineria.dbo.Usuario INNER JOIN Mineria2.dbo.ARTISTA ON Mineria2.dbo.ARTISTA.Id_Artista=Mineria.dbo.Usuario.ID_Usuario 
AND Mineria.dbo.Usuario.ID_Usuario BETWEEN '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND '" + textBox2.Text + "' ORDER BY ID_Usuario ASC"), cn);
```

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you tried to output `comando` to check whether it generates the right statement or not?

Comment: So is using SQL parameters to avoid injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Break it up into a small select...

Comment: Yes this is an sql injection attack waiting to happen, you will find if you use parameters most of these kind of issues will be naturally solved by reducing complexity

Comment: Please post sample data, i.e. a sample of your raw table data, the results of the first query and the results of the second query.

Comment: Hi Alan! Please don't use string concatenation in you SQL scripts because of SQL Injection. You need to use parameters you can see in : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you're putting single-quotes around the field names (should be nothing since you're using fully-qualified names), and around the integers in the BETWEEN statement (should be nothing because they're numbers, not text):

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(string.Format("
Select " + maskedTextBox1.Text + " , " + maskedTextBox2.Text + " 
INTO Mineria.dbo.Objeto FROM Mineria.dbo.Usuario INNER JOIN Mineria2.dbo.ARTISTA ON Mineria2.dbo.ARTISTA.Id_Artista=Mineria.dbo.Usuario.ID_Usuario 
AND Mineria.dbo.Usuario.ID_Usuario BETWEEN " + textBox1.Text + " AND " + textBox2.Text + " ORDER BY ID_Usuario ASC"), cn);
```

Comment: The huge injection issue should really be addressed here. It's a massive security flaw in the OP's code, and is just a matter of time before it's exploited.

Comment: Assuming this code is accessible from the outside world, yes.